# Python 3.2, Pygame "AttributeError: 'pygame.Rect' object has no attribute 'bullet_RECT'

Tags: python, attributes, pygame, rect

I'm making a small game in pygame to learn, and I have run into a problem

I get the error message

```
line 80, in <module>
bullet_rect = bullet.bullet_RECT
AttributeError: 'pygame.Rect' object has no attribute 'bullet_RECT'
```

here

```
for bullet in bullets:
    bullet.bullet_RECT.top -= bullet.speed

    pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, WHITE, bullet.bullet_RECT)
```

even though I have clearly defined bullet_RECT inside the class bullet. Here's the class

```
class bullet:
    bulletsize_x = 10
    bulletsize_y = 10
    speed = 12
    bullet_RECT = pygame.Rect(player.player_RECT.left, player.player_RECT.top, bulletsize_x,bulletsize_y)
```

What's the matter?

Here's the full code **after the edits**

```
import pygame, sys, random
from pygame.locals import *


DIRECTION = {pygame.K_a  : (-1, 0),
               pygame.K_d : ( 1, 0),
               pygame.K_w    : ( 0,-1),
               pygame.K_s  : ( 0, 1)}

pygame.init()
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()

WINDOWWIDTH = 640
WINDOWHEIGHT = 480
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT), 0, 32)
screen_rect = windowSurface.get_rect()
pygame.display.set_caption('skjutare')

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255,0,0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

class Player:
    playersize_x = 50
    playersize_y = 50
    speed = 6
    player_RECT = pygame.Rect(300, 100, playersize_x, playersize_y)
    HP = 20


class Bullet:
    bulletsize_x = 10
    bulletsize_y = 10
    speed = 12
    def __init__(self, player):
        self.bullet_RECT = bullet_RECT = pygame.Rect(player.player_RECT.left,
                                                     player.player_RECT.top,
                                                     Bullet.bulletsize_x,
                                                     Bullet.bulletsize_y)


bullets = [] 
enemies = [] 

#spel-loopen
while True:
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT: 
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_SPACE or event.key == ord(" "):

                bullets.append(Bullet)

    for key in DIRECTION:
        if keys[key]:
            Player.player_RECT.x += DIRECTION[key][0] * Player.speed
            Player.player_RECT.y += DIRECTION[key][1] * Player.speed


    Player.player_RECT.clamp_ip(screen_rect) #håller spelaren på skrämen

    windowSurface.fill(BLACK)


    for Bullet in bullets:
        Bullet.bullet_RECT.top -= Bullet.speed

        pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, WHITE, Bullet.bullet_RECT)


    bullets = [Bullet.bullet_RECT for Bullet in bullets if Bullet.bullet_RECT.top >= 0]



    pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, GREEN, Player.player_RECT)

    pygame.display.update()
    mainClock.tick(40)
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you should start class names with a capital letter:

```
class Bullet:
```

This has lead to confusion between the class (`bullet`) and each instance (also `bullet`) which may have contributed to your error.

Secondly, all of your attributes are class attributes (i.e. they are the same for every bullet) when at least the rectangle should probably be an instance attribute (i.e. different for each `Bullet` instance):

```
class Bullet:

    bulletsize_x = 10
    bulletsize_y = 10
    speed = 12

    def __init__(self, player):
        self.bullet_RECT = bullet_RECT = pygame.Rect(player.player_RECT.left, 
                                                     player.player_RECT.top, 
                                                     Bullet.bulletsize_x,
                                                     Bullet.bulletsize_y)
```

Finally, it appears that you have, at some point, either assigned a `pygame.Rect` to the name `bullet` or (at least) one of the objects in `bullets` is a `Rect`, although that part of your code is not shown.

---

**Part 2:** As I commented, *don't change all appearances of `bullet` to `Bullet`*. The whole point of using upper-case class names and lower-case instance names is so that you don't mix them up. Stick with `Bullet` for the class, `bullet` for a `Bullet` instance.

More broadly, the problem is that you don't understand Python OOP. All of your class definitions only have *class attributes*. You can only ever have one `Player`, one `Enemy` and one `Bullet`. You need to refactor all of your classes, separating the attributes that are common to all instances of that class (outside `__init__`) from the attributes that are unique to each instance (inside `__init__` with `self.` at the start).

The specific error is here:

```
bullets = [Bullet.bullet_RECT for Bullet in bullets if Bullet.bullet_RECT.top >= 0]
```

You refill the list with the `Rect`, not the `bullet`. Replace with:

```
    bullets = [bullet for bullet in bullets if bullet.bullet_RECT.top >= 0]
```

*(note use of lower case - these should be instances of the `Bullet` class, not the class itself).*

Comment: I changed all the bullet to Bullet however the same problem seem to occur.
I'll edit the main post to paste the whole code

Comment: Don't change *all* `bullet` to `Bullet`; use the former to refer to instances, the latter to refer to the class, otherwise you have the same confusion. You will need to provide more code to diagnose the bigger problem; show the parts that put items into `bullets`.

Comment: By the way, how exactly do I refer to instances?

Comment: I have updated my answer. I am not sure exactly what you mean by "refer to instances", but it will generally look like this: `class Bullet(object): def __init__(self, player):` etc. defines the class, instances are created like `bullet = Bullet(player)` (note parentheses).

Comment: So to be able to define bullet to be an instance of Bullet, I have to learn using
 
    _init_ 

and beforehand?

Comment: That is correct. I suggest you start here: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html